# Extract data from email inbox

Tags: email

I have several thousand emails in my Thunderbird email inbox. Each email includes details about orders I've sold. The header includes the SKU and so does the email contents.

I'd like a way to extract the header details of all my emails so I can post in Excel. I need to be able to extract the SKU's from all the emails in a reasonable manner so I can use this data.

Is this possible? Is there a way to simply copy the headers of all my emails in my inbox so I can paste in an excel spreadsheet?

Comment: Any luck with my proposed solution?

Comment: For offline INBOX file dump , if you are programmer and you known python you can use Email class for parse your file and filter only as you want.https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/email-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

You would have to export your emails to gmail, then export the emails as .csv, from gmail. then you can load them into excel. That's how I've done it in the past.